Does my panel have space for a double breaker?
This is my subpanel. It looks like I have slots at top of the bus to add a two pole 40 Amp breaker. But if I do, the outer panel/cover doesn’t fit. There’s only one knockout on the top of panel.
Can I knock out one on the bottom and one on top and turn it upside down?  Or is it like that so I don't add another breaker?



You have a lot of 120v circuits. Couldn't you move 2 adjacent 120v circuits up to the two slots at each side at the top, and then put a 240v breaker in the freed up gap?

Is the "dead front" upside down?

I think it is upside down. Problem is the bus is loaded from bottom up. If I flip it the holes the screws go into don’t line up. Something is just dumb about it.

My xray vision is weak on this, but I see some potential screw holes below the breakers.  Maybe the installer put the breaker assembly too high in the box.

It looks like you could easily move breaker 7 to position 6 and breaker 9 to position 5, freeing up a slot at positions 7 and 9.
You might have some unlabeled and untied MWBCs. If so be careful not to separate them.  Positions 10 and 12 may be such a pair, so check carefully before choosing 8 and 10 as your new empty slot. That may not work.


I like that idea of moving but moving 7 to 6 I guess I’d have to reroute all the wiring for that breaker from left to right side.
I’d really like to put the 2 pole 40amp at 4/6 slots I just need the dang cover to fit. Someone said cut another slot for #4 since 6 has a blank on the cover. Not sure if that’s legal.

Whatever seems easiest to you!  Have you tried just turning the cover upside down?  If that's the problem, it'll take you 30 seconds to figure it out.  Otherwise, moving breakers is 30 seconds if the wires reach, 2 minutes if you need to extend them, 30 minutes if you need to go buy wire.  Accurately cutting a new cutout in the panel wall?  If you have a lot of experience, 5 minutes!    For me: IDK I've never tried so ... an hour on youtube, an hour choosing the right wheel, half an hour planning the cut, 10 minutes cutting it, and if I screw it up, another week waiting for a new cover.

Yeah if I turn panel upside down it doesn’t line up screw holes. Original plan was remove one tab top and one tab bottom and then upside down bc I think that will fit oddly. I’m going to template that and see. Bc of course I couldn’t open it and what looked like it would be two slots empty at bottom is actually nothing.

@jay613 but then you gotta worry if cutting the panel voids some kind of UL listing.

@Huesmann my point was I wouldn't even try it, but you're right, if accurately cutting metal is something you're good at and is your first choice, you do have to worry about that.  I wonder if installing the panel in this strange Dr Seuss manner is non-compliant too?

@jay613 yeah, no clue if there's a clause (NEC or manufacturer) that requires the panel to be installed in a particular orientation!

Looks like the installer did something weird here. They either installed the panel upside down and put the breaker cover on right or they reversed the breaker bus unit in the panel. You could remove the two slots at the top and rotate the breaker cover so you'd have 6 positions at the top. You'd have to make sure the panel cover installed over the breaker cover correctly. Make a template and experiment, with that panel shut off.
The easiest solution would be to get a rotary tool with a cutoff wheel and cut an extra slot above the existing one at the top. You're allowed to punch extra holes in panels but I'm not sure about the cover. It wouldn't cause a problem because the bus slot wouldn't be modified.
